# Extract a substring that is common in ending of first string and beginning of second string

Tags: python, c#, string, substring

Given 2 strings

For example:
`"Hello World"` and
`"World Is Awesome"`

It's not exactly union. I need to extract a substring that common in ending of first string and beginning of second string.

In example above it would be `"World"`, because the first string is ending with this list of characters and second string starts with it.

What is the most efficient way to do it? Could be any language but I'm mostly curious in python and c#.

Here is my solution

```
def union_chars(head, tail):
    match = None
    for i in range(len(head)):
        if tail.startswith(head[-i:]):
            match = head[-i:]
    return match
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Yea, I should paste my effort as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use a `for` loop and indices:

```
def union_chars(head, tail):
    for i in range(len(head)):
        if tail.startswith(head[i:]):
            return head[i:]

print(union_chars("Hello World", "World Is Awesome"))
```

Output:

```
World
```

Explanation:

First, iterate through each index of the `head` string,
and check if the `tail` string begins with the index of the `head` string to the end of the `head` string.Template

Comment: Thank you Ann. I very appreciate it!

Comment: But also, this does not work when there is only one character in one of the lists. 

Like `ab` and `a`

Comment: @Pol Fixed it.-

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified solution base on Ann Zen answer. I think it's a bit more efficient because it does not take `len()` multiple times. And is shorter

```py
def union_chars(head, tail):
    match = None
    for i in range(len(head)):
        if tail.startswith(head[-i:]):
            match = head[-i:]
    return match
```

Comment: Actually, my solution is significantly more efficient. You may test it with `time.perf_counter`.